# Selecting those that does not match

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm very new to this so I will try to explain this as good as I can, also try to explain as basic as you can, thank you!

I have a list with bills that a company gets when they buy something, I'm trying to select only those that have NOT bought anything (therefore their CustomerID is not on the Bill-list). How do I do that?

Here is my code so far (renamed some stuff to english so you hopefully understand better):

```
SELECT Name, Postnr+' '+City as Postadress
FROM Bill
RIGHT JOIN Customer
ON Customer.CustomerID = Bill.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile i prefer `NOT EXISTS` since it's more readable, maintainable and has  no issues with null-values:

```
SELECT Name, 
       Postnr + ' ' + City AS Postadress 
FROM   Customer c 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM   bill b 
                   WHERE  b.CustomerID = c.CustomerID)
```

Another (possibly less efficient) way is an `OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT Name, 
       Postnr + ' ' + City AS Postadress 
FROM   Customer c 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Bill b 
                    ON c.CustomerID = b.CustomerID 
WHERE  b.CustomerID IS NULL
```

Here's a list of all approaches:

[Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

Answer (score 0):

You explained it quite well. You should have made your SQL right from your explanation:
Customer with their CustomerID not in Bill list. Now this would be like:

```
select * from Customer where CustomerID not in (select CustomerID from Bill)
```

Dependent on your database system the syntax could vary slightly e.g. not CustomerID in ...

Comment: Thank you, glad I could make it clear. I tried the solution from Tim, I have no idea what would be counted as the "best" solution, though.

Comment: @MaGi you should choose the best solution based on who gave you the most complete answer. While this one solves your problem, Tim's is better suited for performance and unknown situations (null values).

Comment: Like Tim said it, its a thing of preference.

Comment: @MaGi: i have already added a link to my answer which explains the differences very well.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, Postnr+' '+City as Postadress
FROM Bill
RIGHT JOIN Customer
ON Customer.CustomerID = Bill.CustomerID
WHERE Customer.CustomerID NOT IN (SELECT Bill.CustomerID FROM Bill)
```